# The infinity norm of the sequence $v(n) = n \sin(n!)/(n^2+1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

For a bounded sequence $v(n)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ define $$||v||_\infty = \max_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |v(n)|.$$ Let $$v(n) =\frac{n\sin{(n!)}}{n^2+1},$$ and find whether $||v||_\infty<\infty$.

---

\begin{align}
||v||_\infty &= \max_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\frac{n\sin{(n!)}}{n^2+1}\right| \\
&\le \max_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right|\cdot \max_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|sin{(n!)}\right| \\
&\le \frac{1}{2}\cdot1 = \frac{1}{2} <\infty.
\end{align}

So indeed $||v||_\infty$ is finite.

---

Does this seem like a legal method to solving this question?

Comment: It looks good. However, I think it'd be better to use something like $\sup$ instead of $\max$, since we're not sure that a maximal element exists. (I don't think it does for $sin(n!)$). Another thing is that $n!$ isn't defined for negative $n$, but this is probably just a minor mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Farnight suggested, it is better to use $\sup$. I also prefer to work  on a more concrete level: with numbers, not with sets of numbers. So I would write: "for $n\in \mathbb{N} $, 
$$|v(n)|=\left|\frac{n\sin{(n!)}}{n^2+1}\right|\le  \frac{n }{n^2+1}\le \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} <1 $$
Therefore, the sequence $v$ is bounded."

Note that your write up leaves the part 
$$\max_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right| \le\frac12$$
unexplained, while it is arguably the most substantial part of the computation.